# batch file to start multi-services if the services are not running

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to write a batch file that performs the following functions:

Check if the three services are running
1.If the services not running, start the services
2.Query the services every 60 seconds

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Please learn, [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why not just start the service every 60 seconds. It doesn't hurt anything to try to start a started service. However Windows has settings to restart services when they crash. By default it tries 3 times. But you can change that.

Comment: You could start by opening a Command Prompt window and entering `SC /?`. Alternatively you could take a look at the output from `WMIC Service /?`.